# VisualStudio未使用でUWPアプリ

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

アホなことをやろうとしていますが、お付き合い頂けると幸いです。
タイトルの通りですが、IDEを使わず.NetFlameWork4.6のみでUWPアプリを作ろうと、
以下のソースを作成しました。

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Program class
    /// </summary>
    public static class Program
    {
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks"," 14.0.0.0")]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Start((p) => new App());
        }
    }

    class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync(
                Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Metadata |
                Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Session);
        }
    }
}
```

csc.exeでコンパイルの結果、以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
error CS1525: '>' は無効です。
error CS1026: ) が必要です。
error CS1002: ; が必要です。
error CS1525: ')' は無効です。
```

メソッド形式を使うには、linqをusingするだけでは足りないのでしょうか。
何かご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教授お願いします。すみません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問文に書かれていないので推測なのですが、コンパイルに`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe`を使用されましたでしょうか？

.NET 2.0に含まれるC# 2.0コンパイラーはラムダ式を解釈できません。ラムダ式を使用したいのであればラムダ式が導入されたC# 3.0（.NET 3.5）以降のコンパイラー`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe`や`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe`を使用する必要があります。

ただし、UWPアプリは通常のEXE形式ではありませんので、コンパイルに成功したとしても起動が大変です。各種手順がGUIで用意されているVisual Studioを使用することをお勧めします。

Comment: 仰る通りでした。パスを変更した結果、無事コンパイルが完了しました。
ありがとうございます。

なお掲載ソースをコンパイルして出来上がったexeを叩いた結果、
何も起きなかったことを念のため、閲覧された方々にご報告です。
画面定義が何もないからでしょうな。
Visual Studioは偉大ということで、〆させて頂きます。